# Users to fetch files remotely

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, remote-access

I am using ADO to connect to an access database from an excel spreadsheet using code written in vb. The spreadsheet allows someone to retrieve files stored locally on my machine according to what they enter in certain cells and from interrogating the database. This has worked well which presents the frightening prospect of me now feeling encouraged!...

It is my wish to give a copy of my spreadsheet to people but retain the files and database on my own computer or a dedicated server. ( I do not want the users to be able to access anything other than a view onto the data or the files that I allow them to access). I totally appreciate their are a myriad of alternative technologies that I could and might need to achieve this. But I really am quite a simpleton and would like to be able to simply amend my connection string with something that uses an IP address and similarly with the files. Is this even possible? Can someone advise me where to even start looking for a solution if it is not? I've browsed through stuff on VPN's, application servers, ASP's etc. without even knowing if it is relevant and, as I say, I need the dumbsters solution. I'm happy to read - but what......should I look at VB.net?

Answer (score 1):

A VPN would allow a similar setup to what you have now in as much as your would need to modify the connection string and file paths (to network share paths) but has drawbacks:

- Users/you would need to configure a VPN client
- Your machine would be the host so would need to be always-on with sufficient bandwidth
- Users would be logging on to your machine so you would need to manage access rights/security

This is difficult to scale and a pain in to manage, which is something that is also true of attempting to serve Access content over the internet.

A more standard way to do this would be to:

- Get an ASP.NET hosting account with SQL Server support (or set this up on your machine)
- Migrate the Access data to SQL Server (which unlike Access is specifically designed to support multiple users over a network)
- Update your VBA connection string and make any required changes to your SQL
- Create an ASP page that reads the files stored on the server and returns their content
- Modify the code you have that loads files from disk to instead query this ASP page over HTTP and read its contents

Retaining Access; you could also create a ASP page that executes queries, reads the data and converts it to XML returned to your spreadsheet for processing.